# React Native: App falls back to a black screen after the splash screen disappears for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-firebase

Android app is working just fine. This issue happens only on iOS so I guess there is something wrong with AppDelegate.m file. First time developing an app and so not familiar with Obj-C, so am seeking help here.

This is the error message I get from Xcode:

2021-03-08 23:22:39.621 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue][RCTUIManager.m:374] Could not locate shadow view with tag #93, this is probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and shadow views.

2021-03-08 23:22:39.647 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue][RCTUIManager.m:374] Could not locate shadow view with tag #95, this is probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and shadow views.

This is my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <RNSplashScreen.h>


#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
    FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
    SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
    [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
    [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    [FIRApp configure];

    #if DEBUG
        InitializeFlipper(application);
    #endif

    RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"Pickgle" initialProperties:appProperties];
    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [RNSplashScreen show];

return YES;

}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}


- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
    #ifdef DEBUG
       return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    #else
      return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
}


@end
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!